# Java regex convert

Tags: java

How convert `String s = "[[1, value one, v3], [2, value two, v3]]"` to
`"[[\"1\",\"value one\",\"v3\"],[\"2\",\"value two\",\"v3\"]]"` for parsing since

```
Type typeToken = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>() {}.getType();
List<List<Object>> list = new Gson().fromJson(s, typeToken);
```

throws com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at...

Comment: It is normal that you have this error cause your String is not a JSON... You need to parse it as String, not as JSON.

Comment: That conversion would probably not help much since as M.Be said that string is not valid json (hence `MalformedJsonException`). Did you try manually and did it work? I'd say no but if it worked, what did you get?

Comment: The second embodiment works System.out.println(list.get(1).get(1)); Result = value two

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
    String s = "[[1, value one, v3], [2, value two, v3]]"
        .replaceAll("([\\[,]\\s*)([^\\[\\]\\\"]+?)(\\s*[\\],])", "$1\"$2\"$3")
        .replaceAll("([\\[,]\\s*)([^\\[\\]\\\"]+?)(\\s*[\\],])", "$1\"$2\"$3");
```

For some reason I could not get it to work from the first run - you have to run the replacement twice. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex (without Java escaping of `\`):

```
\[([\d]+),\s*([\w\s]+),\s*([\w]+)\]
```

Details:

1. `\[`: matches `[`
2. `([\d]+)`: first value specifically one or more digits
3. `\s?([\w\s]+)`: second value a "string with spaces" `\s*` check if a spaces are present (zero or more).
4. `\s?([\w]+)`: third value a string with no spaces, also here `\s?` is checking if a spaces are present.
5. `\]`: matches `]`

Java test:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "[[1, value one, v3], [2, value two, v3]]";
        System.out.println("input: " + s);
        String o = s.replaceAll("\\[([\\d]+),\\s*([\\w\\s]+),\\s*([\\w]+)\\]", "[\"$1\",\"$2\",\"$3\"]");
        System.out.println("output: " + o);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
input: [[1, value one, v3], [2, value two, v3]]
output: [["1","value one","v3"], ["2","value two","v3"]]
```